# Detect if user is touching SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to write a program that will detect touches on an SKShapeNode line. Right now inside of touchesMoved I am doing line.calculateAccumulatedFrame.contains(point) but it detects the full rectangle, including the invisible pixels, made rather than the point on the line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Plese, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: all touch detections given to you are going to be based on a frame.  To get pixel perfect detection is a complicated task that has been discussed many times over here at stack overflow.